# Placing a QWebView Over an Existing QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qwebview, qgraphicsscene

I'm trying to place a `QWebView` on top of an existing window that is just a `QGraphicsView` containing a single `QGraphicsScene`. Is there any way to do this without creating a new window?

My goal is just to overlay most of the screen and dim out the stuff on the `QGraphicsScene`, so it puts a "focus" on the `QWebView`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding the `QWebView` to the QGraphicsView, and then positioned it using the `move(QPointF)` and `resize(QSize)` methods.

Comment: I'm new to Qt... any advice on how to do the exact opposite? (I want to show a "loading" graphic between page loads)

Comment: You can probably just set a loading widget as a child of the QWebView. Just have a function show the loading widget when page loading starts, and hide it when the loading finishes.

Comment: Thanks- I wrote it as a distinct question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014431/overlay-while-loading-page-into-qwebview and got similar advice :) Much appreciated